# session fixture is not called and global variable sharing

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I need a fixture (session?) that is initializing variable which will be used in the test to generate test output. I do not need this fixture to be run at each test but only during test initialization.
this variables need to be used in the test to parametrize.

in conftest.py:

```
import os
import json
import glob
import csv
from gbl import *

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--component", action="append", default=[], help="component to test")

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    metafunc.parametrize("code", DTCLIST)

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def my_own_session_run_at_beginning(request):
    print('\nIn my_own_session_run_at_beginning()')
    GlobalDatabase = dict()
    GlobalDataBaseName = os.path.join('c', 'myfolder', '10_Requirement', 'db.json')
    with open(GlobalDataBaseName, 'r') as fp:
        GlobalDatabase = json.load(fp)['codes']

    component = request.config.getoption('component')[0]
    diagCfg = list()
    sources = ''
    if component != 'all':
        DTCFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join('c', 'myfolder', '*',
                                          component, '20_SystemDesign', , '*.dtc'))
        SrcFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join('c', 'myfolder', '*',
                                          component, '40_SystemDesign', '*.c'))
    else:
        DTCFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join('c', 'myfolder', '*',
                                          '*', '20_SystemDesign',  '*.dtc'))
        SrcFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join('c', 'myfolder', '*',
                                          '*', '40_SystemDesign', '*.c'))
    for DTCFile in DTCFiles:
        with open(DTCFile, 'r') as csvFile:
            csvLine = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=';')
            for row in csvLine:
                if row:
                    diagCfg.append({'code': row[0], 'SWName': row[1], 'fileName': DTCFile})

    for SrcFile in SrcFiles:
        with open(SrcFile, 'r') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                sources += line

    GLOBALDB = GlobalDatabase
    DTCLIST = diagCfg
    SOURCESBUFFER = sources
```

gbl.py:

```
DTCLIST = list()
GLOBALDB = dict()
SOURCESBUFFER = ''
```

testdtc.py:

```
import re
import pytest
from gbl import *

def test_dtc_code_syntax(code):
    assert re.match('\d+\.\d+\.\d+', code['code']), "{} does not have a proper syntax.".format(code['code'])
```

I would have expected that the function my_own_session_run_at_beginning would have run but when run the command:

```
pytest -v -s --component all testdtc.py
```

I fall into this situation where the test is skipped

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.0, pytest-3.3.0, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- c:\cad\workspace\environment\python\2.7\python.exe
cachedir: .cache
metadata: {'Python': '2.7.0', 'Platform': 'Windows-post2008Server-6.2.9200', 'Packages': {'py': '1.5.2', 'pytest': '3.3.0', 'pluggy': '0.6.0'}, 'Plugins': {'rerunfailures': '3.1', 'tap': '2.1', 'json': '0.4.0', 'teamcity-messages': '1.17', 'html': '1.16.0', 'instafail': '0.3.0', 'metadata': '1.5.1'}}
rootdir: c:\git\diagchecker_, inifile:
plugins: teamcity-messages-1.17, tap-2.1, rerunfailures-3.1, metadata-1.5.1, json-0.4.0, instafail-0.3.0, html-1.16.0
collected 1 item

Test_Dtc.py::test_dtc_code_syntax[code0] SKIPPED                         [100%]

========================== 1 skipped in 0.04 seconds ==========================
```

Does anyone has a solution to this?

Thank you very much in advance